# const Hoek = require('hoek'); error on server startup on NodeJS v4.2.6

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/juice/node_modules/web-resource-inliner/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:5
const Hoek = require('hoek');
```

am getting error on server startup running on Node v4.2.6. 
Can anyone help me o resolve this issue.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: The above mentioned is the error I am getting in command prompt

Comment: Just that? There's gotta be more.

Comment: I got only this two lines as error.

Comment: @SooryaPrakash Did you ever find a solution?